# History behind Serre's conditions $\mathrm{S}_k$ and $\mathrm{R}_k$ for a commutative Noetherian ring

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ho.history-overview

This is a [repost](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/15636/5031). So far, I've received no answers on HSM Stack Exchange; maybe I do in MO.

In [033Q](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/15636/5031) we find defined what some sources call “Serre's conditions $\mathrm{S}_k$ and $\mathrm{R}_k$” (for a commutative Noetherian ring $A$, one says that $A$ has $\mathrm{S}_k$ (resp., $\mathrm{R}_k$) if $\operatorname{Spec}A$ has it).

These conditions are used to characterize properties of Noetherian rings:

> **Lemma.** Let $A$ be a commutative Noetherian ring. Then:
>
> 1. $A$ is reduced $\Leftrightarrow$ $\mathrm{R}_0$, $\mathrm{S}_1$ hold. ([031R](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/031R))
> 2. $A$ is normal $\Leftrightarrow$ $\mathrm{R}_1$, $\mathrm{S}_2$ hold. ([031S](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/031S))
> 3. $A$ is Cohen-Macaulay $\Leftrightarrow$ $\mathrm{S}_k$ holds for all $k$. ([0342](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0342))

Also, $\mathrm{S}_k$ can be defined for an $A$-module (see [031P](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/031P)), and then $\mathrm{S}_1$ has a characterization given in [031Q](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/031Q).

My questions are:

> (1a) Who defined Serre's conditions the first time? (was Serre himself?)
>
> (1b) Who chose the notation $\mathrm{S}_k$ and $\mathrm{R}_k$ for them? (It seems standard in all modern sources).

In [EGA IV₂](http://www.numdam.org/articles/PMIHES_1965__24__5_0/), conditions $\mathrm{S}_k$ and $\mathrm{R}_k$ are defined in §5.7 and §5.8, respectively. H. Matsumura also defines them in his *Commutative Algebra* (in (17.I)) and *Commutative Ring Theory* (in the remark before Theorem 23.8).

The second point of the lemma above is sometimes called “Serre's criterion for normality” (in EGA IV, this is (5.8.6), whereas in Matsumura's CA it's (17.I), Theorem 39, whose proof is “after EGA IV”). Right before stating Theorem 39, Matsumura says that Serre's criterion for normality is *due to Krull(1931) in the case $A$ is a domain, and to Serre in the general case.* However, there is no “Krull(1931)” in the book bibliography. For these reasons, my other questions are:

> (2) Which paper is “Krull(1931)” that Matsumura quotes? A search for the author and year in [google scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=wolfgang%20krull&hl=es&as_sdt=0%2C5&as_ylo=1931&as_yhi=1931) shows three papers. As I said in a comment to F. Knop, I'm having trouble finding the statement: I think it's about my mathematical German (not the best) and the fact that with my current CommAlg knowledge, I'm not able to read something and say “uh, this is equivalent to $\mathrm{R}_1$ and $\mathrm{S}_2$,” unless it is literally the same.
>
> (3a) Where did Serre proved his criterion for normality?
>
> (3b) Was Serre really the first one proving it? (For an arbitrary Noetherian ring.)

Comment: For 3a, probably in Serre's *Algebre local multiplictés*

Comment: Obvious question but… did you try asking Serre himself?

Comment: According to zbMath, there are 5 papers of Krull in 1931. Four of them deal with rings of power series. So I would check "Krull, Wolfgang: Über die Zerlegung der Hauptideale in allgemeinen Ringen. Math. Ann. 105, 1-14 (1931)".

Comment: @FriedrichKnop Honestly, I think my actual problems with finding Krull's statement are that (i) my mathematical German is not the best and (ii) I'm not currently acquainted with the relevant CommAlg facts, so I'm not able to read something and say “uh, this is equivalent to $\mathrm{R}_1$ and $\mathrm{S}_2$,” unless it is literally the same. I am curious from a historiographical POV to know what Krull's original statement looked like, but I think other person might be have the capabilities to find it much faster than me. (I will edit the post to make this explicit.)

Comment: @Gro-Tsen It's not obvious haha. I might do if in the upcoming days if I don't receive answers.

Comment: @DonuArapura $\def\p{\mathfrak{p}}$I just checked the book and his characterization for normality (Prop. 9, p. 50) is proven for a Noetherian integral domain (according to Matsumura, this case is due to Krull): Serre writes “a Noetherian integral domain is normal if and only if it holds (a) if $\p\subset A$ is a prime of height 1, then $A_\p$ is a DVR, and (b) the essential prime ideals of every non-zero principal ideal of $A$ are of height 1” (he doesn't use the notation “$\mathrm{R}_1$, $\mathrm{S}_2$,” although $\mathrm{R}_1\equiv$ (a); I also wonder, is $\mathrm{S}_2\equiv$ (b)?).